# CakePHP Model Callback, specifically beforeDelete

Tags: cakephp, models

I'm trying to execute some logic before deleting a field.  I have some models that are dependent on the model being deleted, and I want to make sure that image files related to those dependent models are also deleted, but I'm a bit confused on how the model callbacks work.

I know that I define the before Delete function in the model class, but How do I access the data in the current model or dependent models being deleted?

```
function beforeDelete() {

}
```

I'm just a little confused as how to use these callbacks, and I haven't seen any great documentation out there.

**Edit:**
After adding this to the parent model, it seems to always return false.

```
function beforeDelete() {
    if ($this->DependentModel->find('count', array('conditions' => array('DependentModel.parent_id' => $this->id))) == 1){  
        return true;
    } else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Should be obvious what I'm trying to do here.  If there is one entry of the dependent model present in the table, return true and continue the deletion.  I made sure that there is in fact one table entry that is dependent on the object being deleted.  When I execute the delete action it always returns false.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When using callbacks, you can refer to the [API](http://api.cakephp.org/classes) for the class you are extending to check the parameters it accepts. Your implementation should accept, at minimum, the same parameters as the methods you are overriding.

For example, [`Model::beforeDelete`](http://api.cakephp.org/class/model#method-ModelbeforeDelete) is implemented like so:

```
/**
 * Called before every deletion operation.
 *
 * @param boolean $cascade If true records that depend on this record will also be deleted
 * @return boolean True if the operation should continue, false if it should abort
 * @link http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/callback-methods.html#beforedelete
 */
    public function beforeDelete($cascade = true) {
        return true;
    }
```

And also, [`ModelBehavior::beforeDelete`](http://api.cakephp.org/class/model-behavior#method-ModelBehaviorbeforeDelete) is implemented like this (ie. when making a behavior):

```
/**
 * Before delete is called before any delete occurs on the attached model, but after the model's
 * beforeDelete is called.  Returning false from a beforeDelete will abort the delete.
 *
 * @param Model $model Model using this behavior
 * @param boolean $cascade If true records that depend on this record will also be deleted
 * @return mixed False if the operation should abort. Any other result will continue.
 */
    public function beforeDelete(Model $model, $cascade = true) {
        return true;
    }
```

Next, it is useful to know that when saving to a model and passing in the controller's data (ie. `$this->data` in the controller) that data is [set to the model](http://api.cakephp.org/class/model#method-Modelset) (ie. `$this->data` in the model). [This happens during `Model::save()`, currently on [line 1225](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/c159854a172bf25cd4fd95765c7ea0d3305892e2/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L1623).]

In the case of the first example you can access the model using `$this` and in the second example you can access the model using `$model` (as `$this` would be the behavior in that context). So to get at the data, you want to use `$this->data` or `$model->data`. You can also access that model's related models using chaining (ie. `$this->RelatedModel` or `$model->RelatedModel`).

As the docblock comments state, `$cascade` should let you know if this is a cascading delete that is happening (`true` by default) in case your code needs to take different actions when this is or isn't the case; and your implementation of the method should return false if you want to abort the save operation (otherwise, return true when you are done).

There is a [Media plugin](https://github.com/davidpersson/media) for CakePHP which implements [this exact functionality](https://github.com/davidpersson/media/blob/a8db789e0ec767ee4f4ebf7af1a8c8df12768893/models/behaviors/coupler.php#L155-182) that can be used as a reference.

Comment: No problem. In reply to your edit, I tested your code at this end (on 1.3) and couldn't find a fault. It worked as expected, deleting only when there was a single dependent record. I would assign your `find('count')` call to a `$count` variable then `debug($count); die;` to determine if you are getting the expected return value.